# Enumerate in Beamer: Automize only@

Tags: beamer, enumerate, overlays, automation

I would like to split enumerate environment over multiple slides in an automatized manner.

In the following example, I need to write `only@`  for each slide. How to get an automized version of this code?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Only...}

\begin{enumerate}
\item<only@1> A
\item<only@2> B
\item<only@3> C
\item<only@4> D
\item<only@5> E
\item<only@6> F
\item<only@7> G
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `<only@+>` overlay specification at the list level:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Only\ldots}

  \begin{enumerate}[<only@+>]
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
    \item D
    \item E
    \item F
    \item G
  \end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But, this isn't working when I have another `enumerate` environment inside this `enumerate` environment. How to deal with this situation?

Comment: @mert: How do you want those to be displayed? Do you have an example one could work with? I'd suggest asking a [follow-up question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764).